# Resetting windows server 2003 administrator password

Tags: windows-server-2003, password-reset

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reset Administrator password Windows Server 2003 installed on Vmware?](https://serverfault.com/questions/286096/how-to-reset-administrator-password-windows-server-2003-installed-on-vmware)

I have a Windows Server 2003 box for which the password has been lost. I don't need to recover it, just resetting, so I've tried using several Linux LiveCDs for running chntpw but when I try to login into windows it keeps saying my password is wrong.

Can you point at other options please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the docs for `chntpw` recommend not changing the password an instead resetting to blank. After logging in the password can be changed through Windows. I've used it on several Windows installation recoveries, although admittedly not 2k3. See if resetting works.

Answer (score 0):

[ewwhite](https://serverfault.com/users/13325/ewwhite) gave an excellent answer to your question:
[link](https://serverfault.com/questions/286096/how-to-reset-administrator-password-windows-server-2003-installed-on-vmware)

Also, you can try this software:

```
Windows Admin Hack - Linux Boot;
Hirens.BootCD.10.4;
ophcrack-xp-livecd-2.3.1.iso
```

Comment: have not been able to download ophcrack tables, although I only need to reset it, not retrieving it, I'll give it a try

Comment: Windows Admin Hack don't solve your problem? And have you tried to act according to instructions?